# File handling using struts2 + hibernate3 + MySql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, struts2, blob

Long back I have create an web applications in struts2 + Hibernate + MySql. The application is working fine but the problem i am facing is that, I am having a table where i used to save all reports of the users on daily bases. The reports are saved within the table as blob type. Initially the application was working fine, It has been long time the application is running quite good, recently it was been noted the table has too many files within the table and the application is talking too much time for bring the file from the database. Can anyone please tell me some solution for this issue.

Do i need to use separate database for files - a suggestion

Comment: store files in a folder and store its path in db.storing files in db is wrong practice and can harm you

Comment: but how the security of the files, also the application is intranet

Comment: create lock on the folder or any kind of encryption technique for yous file contents

Comment: if it is intranet how can access the files, also when i talked about this files storing in folder everyone is talking about the security

Comment: also Java7 allows file locking but helpful only for the single file not for the entire directory right

Comment: yeah then you can encrypt your files individualy

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: if files are encrypted then how can someone look inside folder???and if you encrypt then you only knows the decryption technique.

Comment: This sounds like something about a not-nicely indexed table.

Comment: @AndreaLigios i am not getting you....do i need to do anything

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to store files in the database directly. Instead you can store it in some other location and save the path in the database. Otherwise you can follow some naming techniques and call the file directly from the location itself, then no need to save the path also.

Comment: if i create a separate application where service runs under different server and a separate database say oracle for handling the files saving and accessing, and say if my application needs to store any files i will access this service and save it and in return i will get an object id where i will save it within my db...........is this doable and solves the issue....